# Testing keyboard accessibility: how to check what is selected with Playwright?

Tags: playwright

I have a React PWA that I am testing with Playwright.

I want to ensure everything in my PWA can be done using only the keyboard, so I want to write some tests in Playwright to verify this.

I use `keyboard.press` to input keys:

```
await this.page.keyboard.press('Tab');
```

Now, I want to verify which element is selected when I press the tab key.

So, for example, say I select an email field by pressing the Tab key three times like this:

```
await this.page.keyboard.press('Tab');
await this.page.keyboard.press('Tab');
await this.page.keyboard.press('Tab');
```

Now, I expect the result to be that I am now ready to type something into the email field.  How can I verify that I have selected a given element?  In other words, what can I use in Playwright to say "tell me the id of the element on the page that has been selected via the keyboard?"

I've been trying to Google this but I don't know the right term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to verify that the element is focused you can use [toBeFocused](https://playwright.dev/docs/next/test-assertions#locator-assertions-to-be-focused) matcher:

```js
await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
await page.keyboard.press('Tab');
await page.keyboard.press('Tab');

await expect(page.locator('#email')).toBeFocused();
```